# How to load a web page in a WebView by clicking on a button using JavaFX?

Tags: webview, javafx

i'm working on a browser and i have a button that button while clicking on it should loads a web page on WebView this is the code that i've traied:

```
@FXML
private void tabfirst (ActionEvent ee) throws IOException { // for tha Chooser frame text.

            String hh = text11.getText();
            Socket socket = new Socket();

    try {
          web1.setVisible(true);
        //open cursor
        panoo.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        que.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        //add
        ancpa.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web1.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web2.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web3.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web4.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web5.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web6.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web7.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web8.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web9.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        //do work
        URL url = new URL (hh);
        url.getContent();
        WebEngine myWebEngine = web1.getEngine();
        myWebEngine.load(url.toString());
        //close the window chooser
        Stage stage = new Stage();
          Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Choose.fxml"));
          Scene scene = new Scene(root);
         stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
              @Override public void handle(WindowEvent t) { } });
        //close cursor
        ancpa.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web1.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web2.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web3.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web4.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web5.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web6.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web7.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web8.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web9.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
    }
   catch (IOException e){
       final  Stage stg = new Stage();           
        stg.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stg.initOwner(stg);
        stg.setTitle("Cannot connect to the internet /n Please Verify your connection internet");
        labelno.setText("Cannot connect to the internet...");
        //close chooser
        Stage stage = new Stage();
         Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Choose.fxml"));
         stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
              @Override public void handle(WindowEvent t) { } });

       //set cursor
         ancpa.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web1.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web2.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web3.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web4.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web5.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web6.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web7.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web8.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web9.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
   } finally{
       try{ socket.close(); } catch (Exception e){ }
       }

}
```

So what's the problem with this code please can anybody help me and thank you soooo much!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...

Instead of

```
myWebEngine.load(url.toString());
```

do

```
myWebEngine.load(url.toExternalForm());
```

... anyway, what's the output in the console? Is there any exception/error popping up?

Comment: Well, then please update your question and post the exception you get from the console.

Comment: sorry i couldn't do that the console connot be on the code feild :(

Comment: I don't get it... Just go to the console, copy the exception text (**and the stack trace**) and paste it beneath your question the textfield of your question...
Which IDE do you use?